# nineveh vs cocos3d

Tags: ios, 3d, cocos2d-iphone

I'm learning ho to develop a game app with cocos2d and it's very very interesting; but when I'm ready I want to explore a good 3d engine to create 3d app.
In the web I noticed this two instruments: nineveh & cocos3d.
Is there someone that can teach me their differences and what's the best?
(I know unity 3d also but I don't like to much it)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the main difference is that Cocos 3d is a game engine, ninevehGL is "just" a 3d engine. I played around with nineveh and in my opinion is the best 3d engine for ios, is just openGL2.0, it is studied for multithreading with OOP and objC in mind (but the ground is mostly C++ and that's a plus, 'cause c++ is a lot faster than ObjC). The problem is that ninevehGL development is going really slow, the dev changed the roadmap with huge delays. I'm not blaming on him because the work he made is awesome but I'm worried in  a eventual stop in development.
Cocos 3d in my opinion is really behind in 3d rendering functionality since it uses OpenGL 1.1, there will be an upgrade in first quarter of 2013 for OGL2.0.
 Unity is probably the best game engine for 3d with Unreal of course but the approach is totally different, the last comes with an IDE and you can't use it with Xcode, the language is also different closer to scripting I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Ive used Ninevegh with one of my apps to show a moving/ rotating 3D model that i created in Blender. Its was incredibly easy to use, and in just a few lines of code it was all up and running. plus its very easy to install. just import the ninevegh framework and your pretty much ready to go.

But at the moment its not as powerful or customisable as Cocos3d. It wasn't easy to get it to work nicely together with Physics for gravity and such forces. Im now kinda struggling to get Cocos3D and Bullet physics to play nicely together but slowly getting there.