# iOS: Develop 3D view app

Tags: ios, 3d

I want to  develop a 3D view application on iOS like the one available in the below link for web.

http://www.amfam.com/learning-center/my-home/interactive-home.asp
"Homeowners version" "Renters version" 3D view.

Sorry for the trouble to give the link and Please suggest your ideas how i can develop such 3D based apps, as i couldn't find any idea to develop such apps.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do just that.

One is to get a 3D model to display in a somewhat easy to find 3D engine. With this, and depending on the engine you choose, you just need to select the hotspots and design the camera animations.

Another way, and it looks like the one Amfam is using, is to have a collection of pictures with hotspots and videos for the transitions. This pictures and videos could be done with any 3D modeling and animation tool you prefer and you'd only need to code the hotspots and link it with video transitions.
You should check how to do the videos. Maybe you should think of a GIF or something like that instead of a regular video.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. I would like to go ahead using Cocos3D, which i think simpler than OpenGL ES native framework. Because i don't have much time, i'll have to try using Cocos3D, i decided. Any thoughts/suggestions please? And, as you mentioned major part from my side would be setting hotspots and the right link to it.

Comment: Set a format for a XML/JSON file that describes the hotspots and the transitions you want to do between scenes. I suggest having the following entities: scene, transition and hotspot. Regarding cocos3d I cannot help you but you may start reading or doing tutorials on how to animate the camera so you understand what's the best way to describe a transition. Don't forget to upvote if you liked it.

Comment: OK. Cocos3D lot of features http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/ including camera related transitions..You thought of asking me to approach using OpenGL ES native?

Comment: @Getsy no, no need to do native OpenGL. Cocos3D may suffice.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! One more doubt, i need have 3D images for house rooms and do Transition for moving from one room to another room based on that hotspot set using Cocos3D API's to achieve exactly similar flash animation used in Amfam link. Is that correct? Please advise!

Comment: You need to have 3D models for the rooms (with textures and materials information and all of that) and for each hotspot in a scene you'll need a transition that represents an animation with the camera that may be a path or a key-frame animation. This is still some high-level talk so there's still a lot to check so the better thing to do now is grabbing some tutorials and see what you can come up with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23185/discussion-between-getsy-and-fabio-oliveira)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start from [OpenGL ES programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and looking at some questions on SO too:

[Choosing 3D Engine for iOS in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068018/choosing-3d-engine-for-ios-in-c)

[nineveh vs cocos3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011622/nineveh-vs-cocos3d)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is it possible to achieve my requirements using Cocos2d?